# How to display only rows that are not empty

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have a small PHP mysql query looking at a table in my database. It's pulling all rows and then echoing out the record.

Problem is I have a few empty rows in the table so what I get is a weird looking record.

This is what I got:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("username", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wallnames2011 WHERE firstname IS NOT NULL");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['firstname'] . " - " . $row['city'] . ", " .$row['state'] . " &nbsp;|&nbsp; ";
    }
?>
```

I want to keep the empty rows out.

Comment: Define not empty, your query shouldn't be returning rows where firstname is NULL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try SELECT column_name
  FROM table_name
 WHERE TRIM(column_name) IS NOT NULL

Comment: Okay so I tried this... problem is that there are symbols that still appear. " - "  " ," and " &nbsp;|&nbsp; " I just want it to check if there is a value then show the record if not then do not display the record and omit the symbols... thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you please provide sample data?

Comment: Sure... here is the test page where you can see the scroll. This is where the records are being displayed http://watchmen.ifcj-digital.org?pmd

Comment: @Matthew use regular expressions...  something like `...WHERE TRIM(column_name) REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]'` or whatever.  Brief tutorial about MySql regex at http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/String/Whereclauseregularexpressions.htm .

Comment: the &nbsp;|&nbsp; shows because you echo it at your while loop as a means of separation between rows. The " - " and ", " is the separation between name, city and state, and it's also you who is echoing that in the loop. I think that the database field is not null, but empty ("", 0-length string, or maybe some spaces). So try `WHERE firstname IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(firstname) <> ""`

Answer (score 5):

why u not put

> Try SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name!=''

Answer (score 1):

You can put an `if(!empty($row['firstname']))` before you echo the row.

Answer (score 1):

Alex's empty check is good, and you can also check all three of them inline if you want to display incomplete records:

```
echo (! empty($row['firstname']) ? $row['firstname'] : "")
     .(! empty($row['city']) ? " - ".$row['city'] : "")
     .(! empty($row['state']) ? ", ".$row['state'] : "")
     . " &nbsp;|&nbsp; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the "where" clause mention all field names like `first_name IS NOT NULL AND last_name IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

To print out only `rowname` and result from rows where result `IS NOT NULL`, try this:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    $i=1;
    while($a = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
            if($value != NULL) {
                echo $key." = ".$value."<br/>";
            }
        }
        echo "-- <br />";
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```